# AndroidRuntime error : Parcel unable to marshal value

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have coded a class like this.but when i'm using this there is runtime error is occured in  this overided method

```
 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeValue(synclistener);
 }
```

Myclass

```
public class SyncListenEntity implements Parcelable {
    private LocationServiceProvider.LocationSyncNotifier synclistener;

    public LocationServiceProvider.LocationSyncNotifier getSynclistener() {
        return synclistener;
    }

    public void setSynclistener(LocationServiceProvider.LocationSyncNotifier synclistener) {
        this.synclistener = synclistener;
    }

    public SyncListenEntity() {
    }

    protected SyncListenEntity(Parcel in) {
        synclistener = (LocationServiceProvider.LocationSyncNotifier) in.readValue(LocationServiceProvider.LocationSyncNotifier.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(synclistener);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SyncListenEntity> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SyncListenEntity>() {
        @Override
        public SyncListenEntity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SyncListenEntity(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SyncListenEntity[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SyncListenEntity[size];
        }
    };
}
```

LocationNotifier

```
public interface LocationNotifier {
     void onNewLocationArrived(Location loaction, String privider);
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
     com.library.gps.SyncListenEntity.writeToParcel(SyncListenEntity.java)
     android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:3835‌​)
     com.library.gps.LocationServiceProvider.enableUserTrackingService(LocationServic‌​eProvider.java:64)
     com.ceylonlinux.multilac.activity.FrmHome.onCreate(FrmHome.java:365)
```

Comment: Please always post the full stack trace of an exception.

Comment: Also post the source to LocationSyncNotifier.

Comment: These are errors i have got

  java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
com.library.gps.SyncListenEntity.writeToParcel(SyncListenEntity.java) android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:3835)
com.library.gps.LocationServiceProvider.enableUserTrackingService(LocationServiceProvider.java:64)
at com.ceylonlinux.multilac.activity.FrmHome.onCreate(FrmHome.java:365)

Comment: LocationSyncNotifier is an interface

Comment: Yes, could you please edit your answer to show the code?

Comment: This is the interface

public interface LocationNotifier{
void onNewLocationArrived(Location loaction, String privider);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use [writeParcel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) to write an object that does not conform to the requirements stated in the documentation.  You can only write values into a Parcel of the types stated in the javadoc.